# CSS - positioning different elements in a container

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a site using skeleton grid & reset css. I have an image at the top of each page with a small section at the foot of each image with some text and an icon at either end which I can't seem to get positioned properly. This is how it is suppossed to look -
[image: PSD Version]

This is my coded version -
[image: Coded version]

(background images are different & agency/business image still to be added)
I can't seem to get the showreel text/icon to move at all and am not sure whether its because of the grid I'm using or my own code. Here's what I have so far -

**HTML**

```
<section id="home">

        <a href="agency.html">Are you an agency?</a>
        <a href="business.html">Or a business?</a>

        <div class="container showreel">
            <div class="seemore">
                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
                </span>
                <p>SEE MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="seeour">
                <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
                <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.container {
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* HOME PAGE */

section#home {

    height: 400px;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 960px;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;

    position: relative;
}



.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  width: 960px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel, .showreel > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.seeour i {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I added your provided CSS and HTML to a codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqoLjJ - as you can see, the "see our showreel" part is aligned to the right. Can you create a live example showing the issue?

Comment: @EdmundReed Interestingly, you're getting the same results as me when I recreate the code without using skeleton.css so it must be connected with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have documented all the changes I applied in the source code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto; /* Changed from auto */
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}


/* HOME PAGE */

section#home {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: inherit; /* Added */
  background: url(http://placehold.it/960x400) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: inherit; /* Changed from 960px */
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.showreel {
  display: flex; /* Added */
  color: white; /* Added */
  align-items: center; /* Added */
  height: 50px;
  width: inherit; /* Changed from 960px */
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  /* padding: 0 30px; */
  justify-content: space-between;
}
/* Added */
.seeour {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
/* Added */
.seeour > span {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="home">
  <a href="agency.html">Are you an agency?</a>
  <a href="business.html">Or a business?</a>

  <div class="container showreel">
    <div class="seemore">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
      </span>
      <!-- Changed from <p> to <span> -->
      <span>SEE MORE</span>
    </div>
    <div class="seeour">
      <!-- Changed from <p> to <span> -->
      <span>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</span>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, will this still work with skeleton.css ? I think this is where I've had the issue.

Comment: Only possible problem I can think of is specificity. You would have to check with the development tools of the browser.

Comment: I've implemented your code and I've still got the same issue on the right hand side with the showreel text / icon. This must be something to do with skeleton.css but how do I disable that just for this section?

Comment: Use the development tools to check the specificity. You would have to use the same specificity to overwrite the skeleton rule. If you have a URL for me I can check for you.

Comment: I have to write that as a rule in the CSS file?

Comment: Yes. Use the same specificity as skeleton.

Comment: I've marked your answer correct because it was, albeit I need to explore this ongoing issue with skeleton. At least I know this is what it relates to now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

so your question is to move the "see our showreel" on the right? If that is the case, then please check the `width` of `.showreel` which is limited to 960px only.

Maybe you can set it to a percentage too like `width:100%` in order to push the `div`'s width all through out the screen.

Comment: No, that hasn't changed anything.